# QueryBatcher JobReport wrong failure number

Tags: marklogic

I am querying documents using a `QueryBatcher` and applying a transformation using a `ApplyTransformListener`. After all batches completed, I want to know if any of the batches failed. The `JobReport` seems to be the way to go for this. My problem is that the JobReport always reports that every batch was successful even if there were failures. For testing purpose batch size is 1 so that each document gets processed in a single batch.

```
final ApplyTransformListener transformListener = new ApplyTransformListener()
    .withApplyResult(ApplyTransformListener.ApplyResult.REPLACE)
    .withTransform(new ServerTransform(transformName))
    .onSuccess(batch -> {
        if (log.isTraceEnabled()) {
            for (String item : batch.getItems()) {
                log.trace("Batch #{}: item {} successfully executed.", batch.getForestBatchNumber(), item);
            }
        }
        log.debug("Batch #{}: finished executed.", batch.getForestBatchNumber());
    })
    .onFailure((batch, throwable) -> {
        log.error("Batch #{}: failed.", batch.getForestBatchNumber(), throwable);
    })
    .onSkipped(batch -> Arrays.stream(batch.getItems())
        .forEach(it -> log.warn("Skipped processing document {}.", it))
    );

final QueryBatcher batcher = dmm.newQueryBatcher(queryDef)
    .withBatchSize(batchSize)
    .withConsistentSnapshot()
    .onUrisReady(transformListener);

try {
    final JobTicket jobTicket = dmm.startJob(batcher);
    batcher.awaitCompletion();
    final JobReport jobReport = dmm.getJobReport(jobTicket);

    if (jobReport.getFailureBatchesCount() > 0) {
        // expected to be at least 1
        throw new MagicException(String.format("%d batches failed to executed.", jobReport.getFailureBatchesCount()));
    }
    dmm.stopJob(jobTicket);
    log.debug("Successfully executed {} batches.", jobReport.getSuccessBatchesCount());
} catch (final Exception ex) {
    System.out.println(ex);
}
```

These are the produced logs:

```
11:04:10.950 [pool-2-thread-2] TRACE - Batch #1: item test/Cat.xml successfully executed.
11:04:10.950 [pool-2-thread-2] DEBUG - Batch #1: finished executed.
11:04:10.952 [pool-2-thread-1] TRACE - Batch #1: item test/Cat3.xml successfully executed.
11:04:10.952 [pool-2-thread-1] DEBUG - Batch #1: finished executed.
11:04:10.971 [pool-2-thread-3] ERROR - Batch #2: failed.
com.marklogic.client.FailedRequestException: Local message: failed to apply resource at internal/apply-transform: Internal Server Error. Server Message: error (err:FOER0000): . See the MarkLogic server error log for further detail.
    at com.marklogic.client.impl.OkHttpServices.checkStatus(OkHttpServices.java:4395) ~[marklogic-client-api-4.2.0.jar:?]
    at com.marklogic.client.impl.OkHttpServices.postResource(OkHttpServices.java:3377) ~[marklogic-client-api-4.2.0.jar:?]
    at com.marklogic.client.impl.OkHttpServices.postResource(OkHttpServices.java:3323) ~[marklogic-client-api-4.2.0.jar:?]
    at com.marklogic.client.impl.OkHttpServices.postResource(OkHttpServices.java:3314) ~[marklogic-client-api-4.2.0.jar:?]
    at com.marklogic.client.datamovement.ApplyTransformListener.processEvent(ApplyTransformListener.java:144) [marklogic-client-api-4.2.0.jar:?]
    at com.marklogic.client.datamovement.impl.QueryBatcherImpl$QueryTask.run(QueryBatcherImpl.java:674) [marklogic-client-api-4.2.0.jar:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [?:1.8.0_222]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [?:1.8.0_222]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_222]
11:04:10.974 [main] DEBUG - Successfully executed 3/3 batches.
```

As you can see there is indeed an error thrown and logged in my `onFailure` listener.

The transformation is quite simple and only for testing purposes. It throws an error if some value is not equal to one:

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";
module namespace transform = "http://marklogic.com/rest-api/transform/magic-test/cat.xml";
declare function transform($context as map:map, $params as map:map, $content as document-node()) as document-node(){
    if (xs:integer($content/cats/age) eq 1) then
        document {
           <cats>
               {$content/cats/uri}
               {$content/cats/age}
               <name>Tiger</name>
           </cats>
        }
     else fn:error()
};
```

This is how my data looks:

```
<cats>
    <uri>test/Cat</uri>
    <name>cat</name>
    <age>1</age>
</cats>
<cats>
    <uri>test/Cat2</uri>
    <name>cat two</name>
    <age>2</age>
</cats>
<cats>
    <uri>test/Cat3</uri>
    <name>cat three</name>
    <age>1</age>
</cats>
```

I am using `java-client-api:4.2.0`.
Why does `jobReport.getFailureBatchesCount()` not equal to 1 even if one batch failed? Do I need another onFailure listener I am not aware of?

Comment: That's not expected.  Please file a bug on the GitHub repository.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Filed a bug at the [marklogic-java-api](https://github.com/marklogic/java-client-api/issues/1119) Github Repo.